# JSON format using c#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am trying to create the following JSON object using C# .net

```
{
    "attachments": [
        {
          "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
          "color": "#36a64f",
          "pretext": "Pre-text",
          "author_name": "Myself",
          "author_link": "http://author.link",
          "author_icon": "http://author.icon",
          "title": "This is my great title",
          "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/",
          "text": "This is the text field",
          "image_url": "http://image.path",
          "thumb_url": "http://image.path",
          "footer": "News Article",
          "footer_icon": "http://image.path",
          "ts": 201601010000
        }
    ]
}
```

I created a class as follows:

```
public class Attachment
{
    [JsonProperty("fallback")]
    public string FallBack { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pretext")]
    public string PreText { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("author_name")]
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("author_icon")]
    public string AuthorIcon { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("title_link")]
    public string TitleLink { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("image_url")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("thumb_url")]
    public string ThumbUrl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("footer")]
    public string Footer { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("footer_icon")]
    public string FooterIcon { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ts")]
    public long TimeStamp { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("author_link")]
    public string AuthorLink { get; set; }
}
```

and tried to use JsonConvert.SerializeObject() on the class but it only ever returned the class properties like this:

```
{
    "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
    "color": "#36a64f",
    "pretext": "Pre-text",
    "author_name": "Myself",
    "author_link": "http://author.link",
    "author_icon": "http://author.icon",
    "title": "This is my great title",
    "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/",
    "text": "This is the text field",
    "image_url": "http://image.path",
    "thumb_url": "http://image.path",
    "footer": "News Article",
    "footer_icon": "http://image.path",
    "ts": 201601010000
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get the "attachments" section in first?  I am very new to JSON and it seems the web method expects the "attachments" array first

Comment: `public List<Attachment> attachments { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add another class and serialize it?

```
public class AttachmentsCollection
{
    [JsonProperty("attachments")]
    public Attachment[] attachments;
}
```

Comment: I used a List<T> instead of Attachment array and it works as intended.  Many thanks.